# Verificar se uma variável criada através do exec() existe

Tags: python, variáveis, exec

Boa noite, crie um trecho de um script que realiza a criação de uma variável através do exec(), porém, como posso verificar que a variável existe através de um for in range?

```
# criando a variável: host5 = 'ativo'
number = 5
foo = f"host{number}"
exec(foo + " = 'ativo'")

# verificando se a variável existe
for e in range(10):
    if f'host{e}' == 'ativo':
        print('ok')
```

A parte da verificação da variável é apenas para demonstrar + ou - como seria o esperado. Obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 2):

É possível usar o `locals()` ou `globals()`

O `locals()` lista as variáveis existentes dentro de uma função.

Já o `globals()` lista as variáveis globais.

No seu exemplo:

```
>>> number = 5
>>> foo = f"host{number}"
>>> exec(foo + " = 'ativo'")

>>> foo
'host5'

>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'number': 5, 'foo': 'host5', 'host5': 'ativo'}
```

Sendo assim, bastaria testar conforme abaixo:

```
>>> for e in range(10):
...     if f'host{e}' in globals():
...         if globals()[f'host{e}'] == 'ativo':
...             print('ok')
```

Ou outra forma:

```
>>> for e in range(10):
...     var_teste = globals().get(f'host{e}', None)
...     if var_teste == 'ativo':
...         print('ok')
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar `dir()` do Python e iterar sobre ele para verificar se existe

```
for e in dir():
    if e == 'host5':
        print('ok')
```

Ou dessa forma para verificar um range de nomes

```
for i in range(len(dir())):
    if f'host{i}' in dir():
        print('ok')
```

> A função dir() retorna a lista de nomes no escopo local atual.

Comment: Bem lembrado do `dir()`. Porém, acredito que o objetivo também era testar o valor. Seria possível com o `dir()`?

Comment: Fala @Paulo Marques , boa noite! Creio que com o dir() diretamente não tenha essa opção. Respondi pelo enunciado que pergunta se a variável existe. Abraço!